# Cannot build the app on Android Studio, google services conflicts

Tags: java, android, android-studio, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing an app using react native and would like to use react native fcm library but for some reason I am having difficulties building the app!

My app gradle looks as below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  compileSdkVersion 26
  buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'

  defaultConfig {
    applicationId "fi.x.y"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
    manifestPlaceholders = [
      'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'fi.x.y'
    ]
  }
  buildTypes {
    release {
      minifyEnabled false
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
  }
  dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "8g"
  }
  lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
  }
}

task exponentPrebuildStep(type: Exec) {
  workingDir '../../'

  if (System.getProperty('os.name').toLowerCase().contains('windows')) {
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', '.\\.expo-source\\android\\detach-scripts\\prepare-detached-build.bat'
  } else {
    commandLine './.expo-source/android/detach-scripts/prepare-detached-build.sh'
  }
}
preBuild.dependsOn exponentPrebuildStep

repositories{
  flatDir{
    dirs "../../node_modules/react-native-background-geolocation/android/libs"
  }
  mavenLocal()
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile(project(':react-native-firebase')) {
        transitive = false
    }
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
  compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'

  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.2'
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2'
  compile project(':react-native-fcm')
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.2' //this decides your firebase SDK version

  compile('host.exp.exponent:expoview:22.0.0@aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'facebook-android-sdk'
    exclude group: 'com.facebook.android', module: 'audience-network-sdk'
    exclude group: 'io.nlopez.smartlocation', module: 'library'
    transitive = true
  }

  compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+')
  compile('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+') {
    exclude module: 'play-services-ads'
  }
  compile('io.nlopez.smartlocation:library:3.2.11') {
    transitive = false
  }
  compile(project(':react-native-background-geolocation')) {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-location'
  }
  compile(name: 'tslocationmanager', ext: 'aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
  }
  compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.2"


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Error I am getting in Android Studio:
All gms/firebase libraries must use the exact same version specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found versions 11.8.0, 11.6.2, 11.6.0. Examples include com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 and com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.6.2 more...

With this warning it seems that the building succeed but when I try to run the app I get error saying as:  Error:Execution failed for task

```
':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex
```

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
  }
}

allprojects {
  repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
    maven {
      // Point to local maven repository
      url "$rootDir/../.expo-source/android/maven"
    }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
  }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
  delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Remove `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'` dependency from project-level build.grdle.

Comment: @whenthemorningcomes   still i get same error msg: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: why do you have two `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`?

Comment: @PeterHaddad that was mistakenly added, which one would u think woul suit best with my other dependencies on the code above?

Comment: `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'` <-- this one

Answer (score 1):

In Facebook ads dependency exclude -> gms

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'){
         exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}
```

And also remove following line project level build.gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

Comment: i still get: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex

Comment: Are you removed classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'??

Comment: yes i removed that and left only with 3.0.0 and clicked Sync so it can rebuild it

Comment: I do already have exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms' on this part compile(name: 'tslocationmanager', ext: 'aar') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
  }

why do I need to re-declare it, or do i need to remove from this place and add within compile ('com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:4.+'){
         exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms'
}

Answer (score 0):

By updating everything to `11.8.0` seemed to solve the problem the build succeeded and the app is running.

Well, I do face now Package is not running at http:192.168.168.244:19901 idk how why, eventhou it seemd to worked once! I is now complaining about the debug folder cannot delete when gradle is building!

Answer (score 0):

`firebase-messaging` and `facebook` have the same dependency `com.google.android.gms`. They have to use the same version of `gms` or might lead to build fail. You should exclude them as @Ranjith Kumar said. If problem still exist (like me) then upgrade/downgrade some of them.

In my case, the latest `facebook` sdk **TODAY** is ver `4.31.0`
which includes `gms:11.8.0`, so I've to use `firebase:11.8.0` for consistent.

BUT `firebase-messaging:11.8.0` has a bug about notification icon.
I've to upgrade it to `firebase-messaging:12.0.0`. But I can't because facebook-sdk is still using `gms:11.8.0`.

and I finally found a stable version of them, FYI

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
api 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.11.0'
api 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.11.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:12.0.1'
}
```

- Won't recommend use this if new FacebookSDK(after 4.31.0) use gms:12.0.1.